# Why does uncommitted change in a branch affect the master branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am new to git and I am trying to experiment with it to understand the concepts particularly the branching and merging.

So here is my set up,

I have a master branch, I create a master text file with 'master' text.
Now I do `git checkout -b branch` and create a branch.
I edit the branch 'parent' file and add one line of text.

Now If I commit this change and switch back to master, It won't affect as It shouldn't, as Branch changes should not reflect in the master branch.

However If I leave the branch uncommitted and switch to master, This change reflect there and git treats master file as edited, When I do

```
git status -s
```

It shows that master file with M.

Can anyone explain to me how the uncommitted changes are reflecting in the master branch?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8111991/1256452

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git keeps your uncommitted changes when checking out another branch, which is very practical.

You can see this as uncommitted changes "belong" only to your working copy, and not to any branch or commit. They are independent. When you will commit the changes in a branch, they will of course change if the checkout has a different version for the file.

The only exception to this behaviour is if the branch change brings an uncommitted file to a different version, it which case the checkout is canceled:

```
A--B - feature
 \
  -C - master
```

Let's say commit B in the `feature` branch changes a line to `foo.txt`, and that you have the `master` branch checked out. You have made a different change to `foo.txt`.

1. You commit the change in `master` and checkout `feature`

   ```
   git add foo.txt
   git commit -m "changed foo.txt"
   git checkout feature
   ```

   Here no problem, the change is recorded in `master` and when you go to `feature` `foo.txt` is changed accordingly.
2. If you don't commit and try to checkout `feature`, then Git will print an appropriate message, and keep the `master` branch checked out:

   ```
   git checkout feature
   ```

   > error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
   >   by checkout:
   >   foo.txt
   >    Please, commit your changes or stash them
   >   before you can switch branches. Aborting

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer, Since I am new with git I don't understand the terminology  very well, However I know function of the commands. So if you don't mind, Can you illustrate your last point with a series of commands?

Comment: So I am having a little problem reproducing what you just told me. Here is what I did, I created a folder git_project, I did git init, and git branch, but it is not showing master branch right now. It seems that only after I commit something that I see master branch. Before commiting when I run 'git branch' I dont see anything. Shouldn't master be created be default?

Comment: sure, the `master` branch exists, I believe that when you have no commits it is just "ghost". Make a first commit and it will appear it `git branch`

Comment: Ok, it seems i am really confused, I am thinking of posting a question related to problem above. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Does staging, but not committing, change anything? Or is the file still considered local and thus also staged when switching back to parent?

Answer (score 0):

In Git or any version control system all the merge operations are to be done on the local machine itself. So, if you have any uncommitted changes on any branch so that they don't get lose/unnoticed they are merged with branch just switched/new checkout. Your changes will always be there unless you use git push. Ofcourse, there could have been a reverse case as well, but it is often more beneficial for the programmer.