# Why is IntelliJ automatically loading changes in my "development" branch into the "master" branch?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm using *IntelliJ* and I have been trying to learn *Git* and *Github* lately. So I have been forcing myself to use it. I have a `master` branch and when I'm working on my project, I work on a seperate branch called `development`. The problem is that the changes I make to the `development` branch such as creating new files and directories are being **automatically reflected** in the `master` branch.

I may be naive, but doesn't that undermine the whole point of branching? Anyway, how to do I get this feature to stop? And perhaps, why is IntelliJ doing this?

Comment: if you are trying to learn git you can use it from the command line. Another thing, Intellij will not make any changes of pushing from one branch to the other...

Comment: Why do I see the new files on the master branch then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git is automatically merging changes from a different branch to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111991/git-is-automatically-merging-changes-from-a-different-branch-to-master)